# File upload multiple error is "Getting unknown property" in yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii, upload, yii2, image-upload

When I'm trying to make file upload multiple failed. When I proccess upload the result is error. The error description can see the bellow. And how the solution ?

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException.
>   Getting unknown property: app\models\Gallery::Batas KRS.JPG

code in controller

```html
public function actionGallery()
        {
            $model = new \app\models\Gallery();
            if (\Yii::$app->request->post()) {
                $model->image = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'image');
                    if ($model->validate()) {
                        foreach ($model->image as $file) {
                            $saveTo = 'uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $model->$file->extension;
                                if ($file->saveAs($saveTo)) {
                                    $model2 = new \app\models\Gallery(['image' => $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension,
                                        ]);
                                    $model2->save(false);
                                }
                            }
                            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Success uploaded !');
                        }
                    }
                    return $this->render('gallery', ['model' => $model
                        ]);
        }
```

code in view

```html
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<h1>Gallery</h1>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'image[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();  
?>
```

code in model

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\validators\FileValidator;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "gallery".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $image
 */
class Gallery extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'gallery';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return 
            [[['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'], 'maxFiles' => 0], ]
            ;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'image' => 'Image',
        ];
    }


}
```

Comment: what is full stack trace ? i.e. line number this throwing error in

Comment: \app\models\Gallery(['image' => $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension]);
This is where the error comes from. You put in a $config-Array into the model class. Check model instance creation.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Object.php#L102

Comment: No @Manquer. And how to solution ?

Comment: What mean check model instance creation @MacGyer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this method of save!

> ```
> if ($file->saveAs($saveTo)) {
>      $model2 = new \app\models\Gallery(['image' => $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension,
>                    ]);
>   $model2->save(false);
> }
> ```

your code should look like this:

```
if ($file->saveAs($saveTo)) {
         $model2 = new \app\models\Gallery();
         $model2->isNewRecord = true;
         $model2->image = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;                
         $model2->save(false);
}
```